# How to convert std::string to QString in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, string-conversion

I am trying to covert a string to a QString so I can display that QString on a QLineEdit or a QLabel. Here is the a piece of the code that I have so far

```
char buff[100];
fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp);

//the buff[0] and buff[1] are two char values that I add up to make a string
std::string latitude = std::string() +  buff[0]  +  buff[1]; 
QString::fromStdString(latitude);

this->ui->lineEdit->setText(latitude);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `QString::fromStdString` returns a copy of the string. But in your code result of this function is just ignored. Try this:

```
const QString str = QString::fromStdString(latitude);
```

After it you will have `QString str` which content is the same as content of `std::string latitude`.

Comment: One caveat to keep in mind is that `QString::fromStdString()` expects the input string to be UTF-8. That's fine on most platforms, but *probably* not what you want on Windows.